# Meteor app runs on iOS simulator but not on physical device (iPhone) on Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, meteor, simulator

We are using Meteor 1.1.0.2 to develop hybrid mobile application. The application works on web without any JS error but when we convert to iOS using XCode 6 then application is unusable when we connect the iPhone on XCode. We are unable to login to application which is based on out of accounts-password package.

On debugging we are getting the following message on console
*http://localhost:3000/sockjs/info?cb=i9iykxy2fvFailed31 to load resource: Could not connect to the server*

We tried using IP instead of local host but no change in results.

The same application runs well on iOS simulator without any issue.

Any guidance to resolve the problem will be highly appreciated

Regards,
Naveen Jindal

Comment: can you post how your call to meteor run